# Link click event by class in javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with some `<td>`s and I have a link to delete each row with the class of '.DeleteMe'.
I have an AJAX post call in jQuery, but when I click on a link, it does nothing (click event doesn't work).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".DeleteMe").click(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var DeleteId = $(this).data("deleteid");
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Merchant/DeleteProduct/" + DeleteId,
      type: "Post"
    }).done(function() {
      $(button).parents("tr").remove();
    }).error(function() {
      alert("Something Went Wrong.");
    })
  })
});
```

And here is the link on the each row:

```
<a class="btns delete-icon DeleteMe" data-deleteid="@item.id">Delete</a>
```

How can I get these links to work?

Comment: what is not working? debugger doesn't hit? any console errors?

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking the link (anchor element) an not some element in front of it ?

Comment: I see no wrong in your snippet, that will work fine

Comment: Are those rows created dynamically, or do the links already exist at the time you're attcahing the event listeners to the links?

Comment: Try to put log and verify, it should work there is nothing wrong in your code. Also check for console error

Comment: @Justcode no console errors.i think the problem is i have multiple links with .DeleteMe class.

Comment: use $(document).on('click','.DeleteMe',function(){/*your stuff here*/})

Comment: @shaaraa that should not be a problem, you can edit your question and try to reproduce in snippet.

Comment: @Teemu i create each <td> that each has a links dynamically. with  foreach (var item in Model).

Comment: @shaaraa use delegate for this, dganenco has given an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, that your rows are created dynamically after your event has been attached. In this case I would recommend to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.DeleteMe', function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var DeleteId = $(this).data("deleteid");
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Merchant/DeleteProduct/" + DeleteId,
      type: "Post"
    }).done(function() {
      $(button).parents("tr").remove();
    }).error(function() {
      alert("Something Went Wrong.");
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, please try to figure out about overall event-delegation process. It's a very powerful JS mechanism.